# Unable to download closure compiler pluggin from the repository sonatype

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml

I am trying to use this dependency in my maven project.

I have added the following in my pom.xml

```xml
<pluginRepository>
    <id>sonatype-oss-public</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</pluginRepository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sandwormz</groupId>
    <artifactId>closure-compiler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

But my build gets failed with the following logs

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TradeSim 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (709 B at 1.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/sandwormz/closure-compiler-maven-plugin/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/sandwormz/closure-compiler-maven-plugin/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/closure-compiler-maven-plugin-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.sandwormz:closure-compiler-maven-plugin:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.821s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 16 17:49:58 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/115M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin com.sandwormz:closure-compiler-maven-plugin:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.sandwormz:closure-compiler-maven-plugin:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.sandwormz:closure-compiler-maven-plugin:pom:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT in sonatype-oss-public (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

But in below link I am able to view the plugin.

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/sandwormz/maven.closure.plugin/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but the `artifactId` is `maven.closure.plugin` not `closure-compiler-maven-plugin`. At least as far as I can tell based on the link you've included.

Comment: Changing the **artifactId** from **closure-compiler-maven-plugin** to **maven.closure.plugin** worked for me, Thanks @DB5